# How to use check boxes in FlatList view of popup menu option, react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

> I am using react native pop menu like

```
import Menu, {
MenuProvider,
  MenuOptions,
  MenuOption,
  MenuTrigger,
  renderers,
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';
```

> Here I want to use checkboxes in flat list view where I will catch checkbox value on click as menu option selection event.

```
<MenuOptions>
 <FlatList
  data={this.state.dataSourceGrade}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <MenuOption value={item.id} text={item.name} />
  )}/>
```

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

You can render practically anything inside `MenuOption` component if you don't mix it up with `text` property - see official examples - e.g.

```
<MenuOption value={2}>
  <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Two</Text>
</MenuOption>
```

And when it comes to "selecting" - if you need full control - you can use popup menu as controlled component.